# Rockshox gold RL bottomless tockens?

Tags: mountain-bike, fork

The table in [this document](https://www.sram.com/contentassets/eab2caf78dc74af0978d3f9e205254e0/gen.0000000005624_2019_fs_oil_air_coil_token_specification_english_rev_a_0.pdf) is very useful, however for my rockshox gold RL it does not specifiy how many for my particular fork (160mm Rockshox 35 Gold RL), can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly about the volume reducers (tokens) are you asking? How many will fit maximum in your fork, or how many are you supposed to install in your fork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the 2020 and [2021](https://www.sram.com/globalassets/document-hierarchy/service-manuals/rockshox/front-suspension/gen.0000000006216-rev-a-2021-fs-oil-air-coil-token-spec-english.pdf) versions.

[image]